# linksys wrt54gl dead

Tags: router, internet, dd-wrt

I have a linksys wrt54gl rev 1.1. I tried to flash the firmware to dd-wrt,and the firmware installation failed. Now i am left with a router that has the power led blinking and no connectivity via LAN. I cannot literraly access my router. It doesn't even reset, i've tried the 30 seconds reset, nothing, light is still blinking. Advices?

Answer (score 1):

From the dd-wrt site, [How to Recover from a Bad Flash](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_Bad_Flash). Given your stated symptoms, you want to consider options 2 or 3 from [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_Bad_Flash#WRT54G.2FGL.2FGS), but *read the entire page* before you attempt anything.

Comment: No DMZ flashes after, the led continues to blink without stoping, no communication with the router is possible.